# Access mysql database online android

Tags: android, mysql, database

We are building a web app and a mobile app, we are building the web app using the mysql database. I don't want to use a separate sqlite database for the mobile app, i want to use the same mysql database. Could anyone provide insights of this feasibility and sample snippet if available on how to connect to mysql database online and extract data

Comment: Why not create a webservice to interact with your database

Comment: Webservice? Any inputs or example on how to create the same?

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose your DB via a service layer with proper security.
Say your web app is example.com and you need to use login. So you would need a service for validating login which will accept username and password in POST data.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/validateuser");
// Add your data   
List < NameValuePair > nameValuePairs = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > (2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "foo"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "md5_string_of_input"));

try {
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     try {
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Something like to post and get response from your web app. Note that this is not a complete answer what you are asking for cannot be answered here

Comment: So, effectively, you are saying to query from the webapp rather than the database by itself?

Comment: @bharath yes you need to expose via another Web Layer, Exposing it directly is not a good option.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, it helped, could you suggest some app which is developed with this? Any app as reference to help it take it up further?

Comment: @bharath Check out http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/